# How to display 'IntelliSense Babel icons in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, babeljs

- How to display these 'IntelliSense Babel Icons' in a WPF Application?

  - Where to find these icons?
  - Is there any API to get these icons?

(I'm going to develop a intellisense feature in a WPF function, when user typing in a text box, these icons will display.)

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Those icons are internal to Visual Studio. You can *probably* muck about in the VS dlls to find them, though no guarantees. I would note that those icons are actually protected by Microsoft's copyright, so using them in your program would likely be illegal; I'm not a lawyer, but do consult one if you plan on going this route.

Comment: Agreed. There's Icon extractors that you can easily find via Google, which will extract icons from dlls and exe files, but as mentioned by Miguel, this bears the risk of copyright infringement. If I were you, I'd just go ahead and search for adequate Icons on [iconfinder.com](http://www.iconfinder.com). You can filter by license type and pick only those free to use.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bb166017.aspx

This should point you in the right direction.